# Suggestions: How to develop consistently ARMv7 assembly with a x86/64 PC without using a emulator

Tags: computer-science, armv7

I need suggestions please.

In my CS degree we are learning assembler ARMv7, we connect by ssh to a Raspberry and use Netbeans 8, that automatically use the **gcc** and **gdb** of the Raspberry to build and debug the assembly. All my devices are x86/64 (except my phone).
 Is there any solution? I'm searching any 'ARM based' free cloud server (IDK, Oracle Cloud??) where i could ssh and work there, or a way to build and debug my code in my phone.
THX anyway <3

Comment: I don't understand why you would not use an emulator in your case: if qemu is capable of running Linux, there a chances that it will be able to run the code you may write in the context of your CS degree. [Cpulator](https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm) may probably do the job as well in your case, as an integrated environment for assembling/executing/debugging ArmV7 code.

Comment: Did you ultimately change your mind regarding the use of an emulator ?